# Apply a 2D map to a 3D array in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, mask

I have a 3D array of arbitrary size `m x n x d` where `d` is the dimension, in this case, a time point. I have a 2D mask of size `m x n` that I want to apply to the 3D stack, and in each instance in which the mask has a value of 1, to set the value of the corresponding index in the stack to `nan`. The way I am doing this so far is:

`imageStack((mask == 1)) = nan;`

However, when displaying an image from one dimension of the stack, i.e. `imagesc(imageStack(:,:,1)` after the process, it is clear that the mask has been applied. However, higher dimensions do not have this mask applied - it seems that is has only applied it to the first dimension and not the full stack of images. Am I missing something in my impelementation of the mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a mask with NaNs, to make the job easier. Your mask may work but you haven't shared it.

```
masknan=mask==1; masknan(masknan)=nan;
```

Then, if you are in a 2016b or newer, you can use implicit expansion for the job.

```
image=imageStack.*masknan; % it will automatically broadcast to the 3rd dimension
```

Otherwise, use `bsxfun`

```
image=bsxfun(@times,imageStack,masknan);
```

Comment: `bsxfun` combined with setting the mask to `nan` for regions to be masked and 1 for regions to be kept worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `repmat` to broadcast your mask to the 3rd dimension:

```
d=size(imageStack,3);
imageStack(repmat(mask==1,[1,1,d]))=nan;
```

Comment: Its just slower and consumes more memory ;)